# Collectionview inside tableview cell not increasing height of collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uitableview

I have `UICollecitonView` inside `UITableViewCell`, Everyting is working good, My `tableview` is loading properly and my `collectionview` too. But in my requirement, I don't want collection view to scroll, instead it should increase its height.
When I am increasing height of `tableview` cell, the collection view inside `tableviewcell` is not increasing. Although I am increasing height constraint of `collectionview` programmatically. I tried calling `layoutIfNeeded` and `setNeedsUpdateConstraint` on `collectionView`, and on `tableview` cell and also on `viewcontroller`'s view. But `collectionview`'s height is not increasing.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve it?

Comment: You need to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` while increasing height of tableview cell.

Comment: It will be better if you share some code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try delegate for collection view

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return CGSizeMake(80, 180);
}
```